# Reach only one file through :80

Tags: security

I have an owncloud server which is using HTTPS (www/owncloud). I redirected all HTTP request to HTTPS.
Now I need to reach one file using HTTP (www/other/directory/file.txt). How can I achive this without making any other files reachable through HTTP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you implement your redirect?

Comment: Redirect permanent / https://mysite/owncloud

Comment: Is `www/other/directory/file.txt` a filesystem path or URL?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Redirect permanent / https://mysite/owncloud
> ```

You'll need to change this to mod_rewrite in order to implement an exception for the URL you want to keep on HTTP. For example:

```
RewriteEnging On
ReeriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other/directory/file\.txt
RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite/owncloud/$1 [R,L]
```

I've assuming `www` is your document root (from your redirect) and so `/other` is a root-relative URL, relative to this document root?

This is also a temporary (302) redirect, so change `R` to `R=301` when you are sure it's working OK.

You'll need to make sure your browser cache is clear before testing.

Comment: What happened to your user name?   You looks so anonymous now.  :(